# Software solutions for visualizing similarity/dissimilarity between pairs of people

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

I have calculations of the similarity/dissimilarity between any two pairs of ~1200 people on a scale of 0-1.

I would like to visualize these relationships on an X-Y plane. Are there are any software tools that can take these relationships and put people close to each other who have high similarity and far away from each who have high dissimilarity?

Comment: What does the data look like for each person? A vector of 100s of numeric features? Are you using a standard distance function or something specific to your domain you created?

Comment: The scores are like so:
- PersonA,PersonB,0.55
- PersonA,PersonC,0.32
- PersonB,PersonA,0.24

The way I calculated these is kind of hard to explain. But basically I found which terms scored highest for a person, mapped those to fields, and calculated field scores for each person. Then I looked for the difference in field scores between people using a modified version of Jaccard, added those differences together, and then divided by the maximum possible score. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Multidimensional Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling). The objective is to identify a transformation of your data that will express the relative differences in similarity with linear distances in 2 dimensions. You will want to use classical or metric based scaling for this.

Here is an example with R:

[image: MDS Plot]

The code is fairly straightforward. The magick is all in `cmdscale` and the use of `vegdist` to create the distance matrix for `cmdscale`. Then you can use R or export the data somewhere else for visualization.

```
## load libraries
library(ggplot2) # for charting
library(vegan) # for jaccard

## simulate some data - 1200 rows, 5 features/cols/fields
features <- matrix(abs(rnorm(1200*5)),ncol=5)
rownames(features) <- paste("P", seq(1:1200), sep="")

## calculate jaccard distances
d <- vegdist(features, method = "jaccard")

## Multidimensional Scaling
fit <- cmdscale(d,eig=TRUE, k=2)

# prepare the data for plotting
mds <- data.frame(
  x    = fit$points[,1],
  y    = fit$points[,2],
  name = rownames(features))

# plot
ggplot(mds, aes(x=x,y=y,label=color=name)) + geom_text(size=1)

## bonus visualization! - a dendrogram
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward")
plot(fit)
```